# Magento 2 Product detail page tab not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, tabs, console, product-detail-page

I am facing an issue on a website that sometimes in product detail page description, more information tabs are not working and it will generate an error in console.

Here is the console log error

```
jquery.js:253 Uncaught Error: Method forceDeactivate does not exist on jQuery.collapsible
at Function.error (jquery.js:253)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.<computed> [as collapsible] (materialize.min.js:6)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (tabs.js:179)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js:5130)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:633)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:5860)
at Function.each (jquery.js:370)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js:5859)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._open (collapsible.js:481)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._open (jquery-ui.js:402)
at $.<computed>.<computed>.activate (collapsible.js:464)
at $.<computed>.<computed>.activate (jquery-ui.js:402)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._eventHandler (collapsible.js:358)
```

**forceDeactivate** function is call in Magento 2 default tabs.js #177 to #181

```
        $.each(this.collapsibles, function () {
            $(this).on('beforeOpen', function () {
                self.collapsibles.not(this).collapsible('forceDeactivate');
            });
        });
```

Please see here how it is functioning now.
[image]

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override tabs.js in your theme or module using requirejs and use

```
$.each(this.collapsibles, function () {
       $(this).on('beforeOpen', function () {
           self.collapsibles.not(this).collapsible("option","active",false);
     });
 });
```

you can set the collapsible option active attribute to true or false.

for further detail kindly check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html#fedg_collaps_collapsible

thank you

Comment: Thanks, @manish-chaubey. but the issue in .collapsible is not found. If I override it will still exist. Did you think it will fix?

Comment: Yes it will be fix. You can also use custom collapsible code like          $('#my-collapsible').bind('expand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});         please check this link  http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/

Comment: what file is this